# Where have my windows sound output devices gone?

Tags: audio, windows-11

Out of nowhere, the sound output list that is accessible from the speaker icon in the taskbar  has stopped showing the sound output devices (see picture attached)

Its a big pain in the neck - I use a few different sources and switch between them throughout the day. I've had to click on the "More volume settings" button to bring up the main screen for setting these up instead.

Any idea why the devices aren't showing?

OS is Windows 11 Home

[image]

Comment: What has changed on your system recently, immediately before you observed this issue? Have you checked your Device Manager to see what your system has to say about the state of the audio hardware? What about Event Viewer? Also, in the Audio settings there's a pretty decent troubleshooter that can do some system resets to resolve a lot of issues. So, what have you tried?

Comment: Thanks very much. 

I looked at the trouble-shooter and it listed a bunch of, what I would have thought as inconsequential errors to do with not knowing if theres a jack connection or not on the various devices. I followed one of them through and it put all the outputs back in the menu as before. Dont know why it worked but it did. cheers!

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @music2myear, I ran a basic troubleshooter and that seemed to result in things being returned to normal.